# using module.exports in node to have better structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre',genreSchema);

//Get Grenres
module.exports.getGenres = function (callback, limit) {
    Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

//Add Genre
module.exports.addGenre = function (genre, callback) {
    Genre.create(genre, callback);
}
```

Above code is working but I felt the code is ugly because I have to write so many times of module.exports. How to simplify above code?

Comment: This is more suited for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single object assigned to `module.exports` like below -

```
var Genre =  mongoose.model('Genre',genreSchema);

//Get Grenres
var getGenres = function (callback, limit) {
    Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

//Add Genre
var addGenre = function (genre, callback) {
      Genre.create(genre, callback);
}

module.exports = {

      getGenres : getGenres,

      addGenres : addGenre
};
```